# How to canonicalize UndirectedEdge with good performance?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

When programming with graphs, it is sometimes important that `UndirectedEdge[a,b]` and `UndirectedEdge[b,a]` are treated as equivalent. Up to M12.0 it was possible to handle this by temporarily setting `Orderless` on `UndirectedEdge`. But in M12.1, `UndirectedEdge` can have three arguments, so `Orderless` cannot be used.

What is a good alternative that does not compromise peformance?

This is [the workaround](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/Common.m#L237) I have been using in IGraph/M:

```
canonicalEdgeBlock::usage = "canonicalEdgeBlock[expr] evaluates expression while making sure that all UndirectedEdge expressions inside are ordered canonically.";
SetAttributes[canonicalEdgeBlock, HoldAllComplete]

(* In M12.1 and later, UndirectedEdge can have 3 arguments, so we cannot canonicalize simply with Orderless. *)
(* TODO  The workaround /; Not@OrderedQ[{a, b}] is 10x slower than Orderless! *)
If[$VersionNumber >= 12.1,
  canonicalEdgeBlock[expr_] :=
      Internal`InheritedBlock[{UndirectedEdge},
        Unprotect[UndirectedEdge];
        UndirectedEdge[a_, b_, rest___] /; Not@OrderedQ[{a, b}] := UndirectedEdge[b, a, rest];
        expr
      ]
  ,
  canonicalEdgeBlock[expr_] :=
      Internal`InheritedBlock[{UndirectedEdge},
        SetAttributes[UndirectedEdge, Orderless];
        expr
      ]
]
```

It comes at a cost of a 5x to 10x slowdown. I am looking for solutions that are faster.

[Here's an example use of this utility function](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/Utilities.m#L41) in IGraph/M.

Comment: What about comparing the adjacency matrices instead? In general, I find working with the symbolic expressions for directed/undirected edges super inefficient...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am looking for a solution that ensures that undirected edges are always ordered canonically. Sometimes one must work with edges directly. For example, a function may take edges as input. Adjacency matrices can be applied in specific situations only. Also, some adjacency matrix manipulation, such as `AdjacencyGraph`, is also terribly slow.